# Computer Aided Translation and Xcode

Tags: xcode, internationalization, translation

Is it somehow possible to use CAT Tools (Computer Aided Translation) like [Swordfish](http://www.maxprograms.com/products/swordfish.html) in any senseful way to get i18n done? Copy/pasting strings is error prone and any MS Word is not exactly a pro application for translations. 
Any other app/system/format that could work well with XCode for that job?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like AppleGlot is such a tool I looked for. It doesn't translate, but extracts strings and allows incremental localization. It has XLIFF support (as Swordfish, mentioned above).

AppleGlot is available in the developers.apple.com area.